# How to resolve this error "Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode: open ios/Runner.xcworkspace"

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have created a flutter project which is linked with firebase.
It works fine with android devices but getting an error when trying to run it at ios device for the first time.

**below the output of `flutter run` command:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Replace the info in the box "Bundle Identifier" (in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruja7.png)), just replace it as "com.example.youremailID.com"

Comment: Great this solved my problem. 

you need to do this if your apple developer account doesn't have the bundle identifier tied to it yet.

in this case, just do 'com.example.your-email'

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works, try going to the iOS folder and running the Xcode workspace project. Once it successfully runs, quit it and run the app through your IDE again, vscode or AS whichever one you use.